# Sql server restore stuck in "restoring" state

Tags: sql-server, restore

If I restore from Sql Server no problem, but if I do it through my application, the database is stuck in "restoring state".
I found some advice saying to put noRecovery = false, but this didn't change anything.

If I remove the "with move" option, it works: after the restore the DB is in a normal state.

The thing that I would like to understand is: does "with move" modify a sql server table?

Because if I launch the restore the first time without "with move" it says that he could not find the specified path. Otherwise, if I launch the restore with this option, and then one second time without it, it works. So there must be some tables that sql server uses to map the logical name with a physical path, how can I modify this table?

Here is the code:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True", database.SqlServerId, database.Name));

ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);
Restore rstDatabase = new Restore();
rstDatabase.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
rstDatabase.Database = backupFile.Name;
BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(backupFile.FileName, DeviceType.File);
rstDatabase.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
rstDatabase.ReplaceDatabase = true;
rstDatabase.NoRecovery = false;


string dbLogicalName = "";
string logLogicalName = "";

sqlConnection.Open();


SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(string.Format("RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '{0}'", backupFile.FileName), sqlConnection);

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.GetString(2) == "D")
            dbLogicalName = reader.GetString(0);
        if (reader.GetString(2) == "L")
            logLogicalName = reader.GetString(0);
    }
}

reader.Close();

rstDatabase.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(dbLogicalName, backupFile.DatabaseFile));
rstDatabase.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logLogicalName, backupFile.LogsFile));

//Restore

rstDatabase.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
rstDatabase.Devices.Remove(bkpDevice);
sqlConnection.Close();
connection.Disconnect();
```

Comment: Rather than even think about hacking some mapping table, fix the problem: fix your broken restore code. Workarounds are not necessary for what you want. Post the code and use SQL Profiler to see what got executed.

Comment: In Sql Profiler there isn't the RECOVERY option, even if I wrote rstDatabase.NoRecovery = false. But this isn't the problem, since in SQL Server if I remove RECOVERY, the state isn't stuck to Restoring. In Sql profiler there is the option NOUNLOAD for the query launched from the application, but this isn't the problem, since if I put NOUNLOAD in Sql Server, the state of the db returns normal after the restore. -------> NO SOLUTION

Comment: Can you get it to work with a manually constructed statement in SSMS? (Yes, you can.) Find the difference to what SMO executes. There obviously *is* a difference.; Please also post any error you are getting. What is your interpretation of that error?

Comment: If I take in Profiler the query that is launched by the app and run it in SSMS, I have no problem, but if the query is launched by the app the db status remains "restoring". I am thinking that maybe this difference is due to the fact that the command from the app goes in timeout, I will test this.

Comment: Just making sure: You are not catching and swallowing all exceptions, are you? Set the debugger to break on all exceptions. There should be none. Ctrl-Alt-E.

Comment: Yes I was swallowing the timeout exception, so now I have increased the timeout for the calling function: but still the error. The only solution was to avoid the C# Restore class and just execute a SqlCommand with the restore in Transact-Sql. Thank you for your time.

Comment: For this very reason you don't swallow exceptions. Hiding an error does not make it not happen.; I think you should just find a way to set the timeout. It is hard to believe that the Restore class does not support an increased timeout. That would mean that you cannot restore databases that takes longer than 30s(!). Just for this small problem I'd not throw away all the automation and features that SMO provides. https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=smo+restore+timeout

Comment: In my previous comment I said "I have increased the timeout" so this is not the problem (the timeout was in the call to WCF, not to Smo). I'll let you know if I find out more, but so far if I call the restore from my application, I see that in Sql profiler the restore is started and then finishes, but the database does not change its restoring state.

Comment: Similar problem, didn't solve my case: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11dfd5f1-9fde-443f-afd1-cd76a6861d0b/smo-restore-the-db-is-stuck-in-restoring-state?forum=sqlsmoanddmo     I think that Microsoft should see this bug

Answer (score 0):

The thing that I would like to understand is: does "with move" modify a sql server table?

Not necessarily, unless you modify the default databases path in the instance, which you could do in SSMS following these steps: 
 **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/view-or-change-the-default-locations-for-data-and-log-files**

But as someone said, try to fix that on your own application. Do not attempt to modify this on the system database. It could bring unexpected results if you do that.

I think you know that, but **WITH MOVE**  tells the SQL Server to reallocate the restored database in different path than the default path.